# Show Username in Navbar using LDAP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ldap

I am working in MVC Project and trying to login automatically without login page, I am done with coding part for automatic, Now i want to show the logged-in username(Submitter_Name) in Navigation bar, I am confused of how to do. Below is the code in method

```
   public static string GetUserInfo()
    {

        string username = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
        string MSID = username.Substring(username.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
        UserInfo a = UserCommon.propertyload(MSID);
        Submitter_Name = a.FName + " " + a.LName;

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a.FName + "," + a.LName, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });
    }
```

Below is the navigation bar code for username

```
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Hi " + User.Identity.Name, "GetUserInfo", "UserCommon", " ", new { @class = "Name", @style = "color:#ffffff;" })</li>
```

Comment: Add some code for your `NavigationBar`

Comment: What exactly is not working?, Is the username not displaying? or the link is not displaying the correct data?

Comment: i wanted to display submitter_name field in navigation bar thats all